# Order By Statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to order the Time in ASC for the below query. I tried adding ORDER BY after WHERE clause but can't get the result as join statements are used. I have added the full sql query here.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_GetFlightInfo]
    (
    @Origin NVARCHAR(50)=null,
    @Destination NVARCHAR(50)=null,
    @FlightNo NVARCHAR(50)= null
    )
AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
 IF @FlightNo IS NULL
 (
        SELECT tfs.FlightNo,tfs.Origin,tfs.Destination,tfs.[Time],tfs.RevisedTime,tfSSS.DescriptionName, tfSS.FlightStatus from tblFlightSchedule tfs
       INNER JOIN tblFlightStatus tfSS ON tfs.FSId= tfSS.FSId 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN tblFlightStatusDescription tfSSS ON tfSSS.FSDId= tfs.FSDId
        where tfs.Origin=@Origin and tfs.Destination =@Destination
        ORDER BY tfs.[Time];
        )
        ELSE IF @FlightNo IS NOT NULL
        (

                SELECT tfs.FlightNo,tfs.Origin,tfs.Destination,tfs.[Time],tfs.RevisedTime,tfSSS.DescriptionName, tfSS.FlightStatus from tblFlightSchedule tfs
     INNER JOIN  tblFlightStatus tfSS ON tfs.FSId= tfSS.FSId 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN tblFlightStatusDescription tfSSS ON tfSSS.FSDId= tfs.FSDId
       where tfs.Origin=@Origin and tfs.Destination =@Destination and tfs.FlightNo=@FlightNo and tfs.FlightNo =@FlightNo
        ORDER BY tfs.[Time];
        )

        END
```

Comment: What is wrong with using `ORDER BY tfs.[Time]` ?  Can you show the actual query you attempted?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Incorrect syntax near Order By, expecting ), UNION or EXCEPT if i place   ORDER BY tfs.[Time] after where condition.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your query, which leads me to suspect that what generated that error is not what you posted in your question.

Comment: The query you've shown does not exhibit any syntax errors. Don't ask questions about queries that are "something like" your actual queries, without having verified that they're similar enough to exhibit the same behaviours you're asking about.

Comment: No, **that** query in your question doesn't. I've run it. Help us to help you by giving us the means to *reproduce* the error you're seeing. At the moment, we cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put:

```
SELECT tfs.FlightNo,tfs.Origin,tfs.Destination,tfs.[Time],tfs.RevisedTime,
       tfSSS.DescriptionName, tfSS.FlightStatus
FROM tblFlightSchedule tfs
INNER JOIN  tblFlightStatus tfSS ON tfs.FSId= tfSS.FSId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblFlightStatusDescription tfSSS ON tfSSS.FSDId= tfs.FSDId
WHERE tfs.Origin=@Origin and
      tfs.Destination =@Destination and
      (
         tfs.FlightNo =@FlightNo or
         @FlightNo is null
      )
ORDER BY tfs.[Time];
```

As the code inside your stored procedure. No need for the `IF` and duplicating the query.

The main issue in your existing code is that SQL Server uses `BEGIN` and `END` to enclose blocks of code - not brackets `()`. So an [`IF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) should look like:

```
IF <Something>
BEGIN
  --If block
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  --Else block
END
```